# invalid json response in php when json response inside json response

Tags: json, drupal, jsonresponse

i have try to print `json response` but `""` are added to my `json response`

i tried below code `php` and `id` generated by `drupal field`

```
<?php
$data = array("title"=>"test","body"=>"test body");
$php = json_encode($data,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
echo json_encode(array("php"=>$php,"id"=>10));
?>
```

**output :**

```
{"php":"{\"title\":\"test\",\"body\":\"test body\"}","id":10}
```

but i want output like below

```
{"php":{"title":"test","body":"test body"},"id":10}
```

i added some more code for above problem

```
{"php":"{\"title\":\"test\",\"body\":\"test body\"}","id":10}
```

why not remove `json_encode` from `echo json_encode($php);`

how i can get above output` second time

Comment: why doenvote ? see my code first

Comment: @mickmackusa see my edited code

Answer (score 3):

You're encoding in JSON two times :

```
$data = array("title"=>"test","body"=>"test body");
$php = json_encode($data,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
echo $php ; // remove json_encode() here
```

---

After question edit:

```
$data = array("title"=>"test","body"=>"test body");
echo json_encode(array("php"=>$data,"id"=>10));
```

Comment: @Bhargav No need to json_encode, just add $data in your initial array. `$data=['title'=>'test'];$array=['php'=>$data,'id'=>10];echo json_encode($array);`

Comment: @Bhargav do all of your array modifications before encoding.  Add all relevant question details to your question as an edit

Comment: @Bhargav So, decode, insert, encode : `$array=json_decode($json,true);$array['php']=$data;echo json_encode($array);`

Comment: but i can only `print or echo` the output not set inside code because `global php` take output inside `''(single quate)`

Comment: i tried your suggest code but output like `[
    {
        "php": "Array",
        "nid": "8075"
    }
]`

Comment: @Bhargav Did you solve your issue ? Did you check the updated anwser?

Comment: you know about `drupal` because problem generated in drupal

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply do this,

```
<?php
    $data = array("title"=>"test","body"=>"test body");
    echo json_encode(array("php"=>$data,"id"=>10));
?>
```

Comment: @Bhargav What exactly you want?